# Отображение выбранных параметров поиска на странице результатов.

Tags: html, django

Имеется несколько меню, в которых выбираются критерии для поиска. Как сделать так, что бы после поиска (т.е. на странице с результатами поиска) в этих меню отображались те пункты, которые мы выбрали? Догадываюсь, что нужно шаблонными тегами пошаманить, но как...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В форме, которая содержит набор опций, можно задать [начальные](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) значения, которые были сохранены после предыдущей отправки формы.

Comment: Черт, и как это я сам не догадался? Ознакомлюсь, как сделаю - отпишусь.